# Is there a way to further query using the previous query conditions in eloquent of Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let say I have a query like below:

```
$firstQueryResult = ItemModel::where('type', 'myType');
$firstQueryResult = $firstQueryResult->where('size', '>', '10');
$firstQueryResult = $firstQueryResult->where('price', '>', '10');
//many other condition.....
$firstQueryResult = $firstQueryResult->paginate(10);
```

Now, I have a very similar query, which basically is the same as the first query except one condition, so I tried to do something like this:

```
$firstQueryResult = ItemModel::where('type', 'myType');
$firstQueryResult = $firstQueryResult->where('size', '>', '10');
$firstQueryResult = $firstQueryResult->where('price', '>', '10');
//many other condition.....
$secondQueryResult = $firstQueryResult->where('special', 'true')->count();
$firstQueryResult = $firstQueryResult->paginate(10);
```

While the second query works, first query now also take the extra condition of the second query. I am quite sure even in later development, these 2 queries will be very similar, so for better maintain in the future, I don't want to do a copy and paste of the first query. Is there a way to reuse the conditions set in first query without messing with the first query?

P.S. I am using laravel 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides @herrjeh42 's answer, I found that using clone can prevent the problem too.

Using the above example:

```
$firstQueryResult = ItemModel::where('type', 'myType');
$firstQueryResult = $firstQueryResult->where('size', '>', '10');
$firstQueryResult = $firstQueryResult->where('price', '>', '10');
//many other condition.....
$secondQueryResult = clone $firstQueryResult;
$secondQueryResult = $secondQueryResult->where('special', 'true')->count();
$firstQueryResult = $firstQueryResult->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can glue queries together like this and reuse the query parts:

```
public function getItem() {
    $query = ItemModel::where('type', 'myType');
    $query = $this->queryPriceSize($query);
    //... paginate...
}

protected function queryPriceSize($query) {
    $query->where('size', '>', '10');
    $query->where('price', '>', '10');
    return $query;
}
```

Another option are query scopes as explained here:
 https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes